# Login to parscoders.com using requests lib

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to login to https://parscoders.com website using requests library but i can't figure out why my code doesn't work properly. As the network tab of chrome dev tools shows, when i use the browser to login, the payload which is used to login the user contains `_username`, `_password`, `_submit` and `_csrf_token` fields, and the last field is empty. any way even by passing the payload, login does not happen to me

here is my code:

```
    with requests.Session() as s:
        login_url = 'https://www.parscoders.com/login_check'

        # send post login
        payload = {'_username': USERNAME, '_password': PASSWORD, '_submit': "ورود", '_csrf_token': ""}
        # headers = {'refer': 'https://parscoders.com/login', 'origin': 'https://parscoders.com',
        #            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36'}
        r = s.post(login_url, data=payload)

        # make a request to check if login was successful
        res = s.get('https://www.parscoders.com/dashboard')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.html)
```

and this is the content of `r.text`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html dir="rtl"><head><!-- Basic --><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="description" content="پارسکدرز رابط تقاضا و اجرا. درخواستی برای پروژه خود ثبت نمایید و از چند هزار مجری و متخصص پیشنهاد قیمت دریافت نمایید." /><meta name="keywords" content="فریلسنر,آزادکار,انجام پروژه,کسب درآمد,بازار کار,دورکاری,برونسپاری,پروژه, کارفرما, سفارش طراحی سایت,
              سفارش ترجمه,سفارش تایپ, پروژه دانشجویی, برنامه نویسی متلب, ساخت اپلیکیشن, طراحی وب, طراحی لوگو"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><title>پارسکدرز  - اولین بازار کار آنلاین ایران </title><!-- Favicon --><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png" type="image/png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"><!-- Mobile Metas --><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><!-- Vendor CSS --><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/plugins/fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/plugins/bootstrap-rtl/bootstrap-rtl.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/plugins/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css" media="screen"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/plugins/owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css" media="screen"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" media="screen"><!-- Theme CSS --><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/css/rtl-theme.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/css/rtl-theme-elements.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/css/rtl-theme-blog.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/css/rtl-theme-shop.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/css/theme-animate.css"><!-- Current Page CSS --><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/plugins/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" media="screen"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/plugins/circle-flip-slideshow/css/component.css" media="screen"><!-- Skin CSS --><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/css/skins/default.css"><!-- Theme Custom CSS --><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/landing/css/custom.css"><!-- Head Libs --><script src="/assets/landing/plugins/modernizr/modernizr.js" async></script></head><body><div class="body"><header id="header" class="narrow" data-plugin-options='{"alwaysStickyEnabled": true, "stickyEnabled": true, "stickyWithGap": false, "stickyChangeLogoSize": false}'><div class="container"><div class="logo"><a href="/"><img alt="پارسکدرز" width="68" height="68" src="/assets/landing/img/logo.png"></a><h3 class="word-rotator-title home-rotator-title mb-sm hidden-xs">
                            پارسکُدرز
                            <strong class="inverted strong-inverter"><span data-plugin-options="{&quot;delay&quot;: 2000}" class="word-rotate active"><span class="word-rotate-items" style="width: 176px; top: -92px;"><span>اولین</span><span>مقرون به صرفه ترین</span></span></span></strong>
                            بازار کار آنلاین ایران
                        </h3></div><button class="btn btn-responsive-nav btn-inverse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-main-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></div><div class="navbar-collapse nav-main-collapse collapse"><div class="container"><ul class="social-icons"><li class="instagram"><a href="https://instagram.com/parscoders" target="_blank" title="Instagram">Instagram</a></li><li class="linkedin"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/parscoders" target="_blank" title="Linkedin">Linkedin</a></li><li class="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/parscoders" target="_blank" title="Twitter">Twitter</a></li></ul><nav class="nav-main mega-menu"><ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main" id="mainMenu"><li class="active"><a class="" href="/register/">
                                            ثبت نام رایگان
                                        </a></li><li class="dropdown"><a class="" href="/login">
                                            ورود
                                        </a></li><li class="dropdown"><a class="" href="/faq">
                                        روش کار ما
                                    </a></li></ul></nav></div></div></header><div role="main" class="main"><section class=""><div class="container-fluid home-top-two-choice"><div class="row" ><h1 class="col-md-12 text-center main-h1-homepage">
                        برای پروژه خودتون نیروی کار دورکار و فریلنسر استخدام کنید.
                    </h1><div class="col-md-6 text-center"><h2 class="home-choice-title text-center">پروژه ای برای انجام داری؟</h2><p class="home-choice-subtitle text-center">پروژه رو ثبت کن و پیشنهاد دریافت کن</p><i class="far fa-list-alt home-choice-icon" data-appear-animation="fadeInRight" data-appear-animation-delay="1000"></i><center><a href="/my-project/create" class="btn btn-3d btn-tertiary mr-xs mb-sm btn-lg choice-cta" type="button">ثبت سفارش پروژه
                                                            </a></center></div><div class="col-md-6 text-center"><h2 class="home-choice-title text-center">مهارت در انجام کاری داری؟</h2><p class="home-choice-subtitle text-center">به درخواست ها سر بزن و ببین کدوم رو می تونی انجام بدی</p><i class="fa fa-magic home-choice-icon" data-appear-animation="fadeInRight" data-appear-animation-delay="1600"></i><center><a href="/project/index" class="btn btn-3d btn-tertiary mr-xs mb-sm btn-lg choice-cta" type="button">دیدن لیست درخواست ها</a></center></div></div></div></section><section class="section section-primary home-stat-row1"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="counters counters-text-light"><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="counter"><strong data-append="+" data-to="26189">+26189</strong><label style="margin-bottom: 15px;">خریدار راضی</label></div></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"><div class="counter"><strong data-append="+" data-to="40292">+40292</strong><label>پروژه موفق</label></div></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><div class="counter"><strong data-append="+" data-to="139926">+139926</strong><label>متخصص</label></div></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs"><div class="counter"><strong data-append="+" data-to="11">+11</strong><label>سال سابقه فعالیت</label></div></div></div></div></div></section><section class="section mt-none pb-none"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h2 class="home-h2" style="margin-bottom: 5px">چه کارهایی در پارسکدرز انجام می شود؟</h2><h5>
                            ما رابط تقاضا و اجرا هستیم. در پارسکدرز <span class="blue-highlight"> خریداران </span> درخواست خود را به صورت عمومی یا خصوصی مطرح می کنند تا توسط <a href="/فریلنسر" target="_blank">مجریان (فریلنسرها)</a> انجام شود. هر کاری که بتوان در بستر اینترنت انجامش داد. کارهایی از قبیل:
                        </h5><!-- Begin Popup 1 --><div id="popupProject1" class="popup-inline-content"><h2 class="mt-lg">تایپ</h2><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive mb-lg" alt="" src="/assets/landing/img/projects/typing.jpg"></div><div class="col-md-7"><h4 class="heading-primary mb-sm">نیاز به <strong>تایپ</strong> چیزی داری؟</h4><p class="iraniansans-light-font">توی پارسکدرز مجریانی وجود دارند که سفارش های تایپ رو با قیمتی رقابتی انجام میدن. کافیه فایلی رو که نیاز داری تایپ بشه به همراه توضیحات لازم ارسال کنی و کار رو شروع کنی.</p><a href="/my-project/create" class="btn btn-primary">سفارش پروژه تایپ</a><span class="arrow hlb"></span><hr class="solid tall"><h4 class="heading-primary mt-lg">مراحل انجام کار</h4><ul class="list list-icons"><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ثبت درخواست</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> دیده شدن توسط مجریان</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ارسال پیشنهاد برای شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> انتخاب بهترین پیشنهاد</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> گروگذاری وجه از سوی شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> تحویل کار از سوی مجری</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> آزاد کردن وجه از جانب شما</li></ul></div></div></div><!-- End Popup 1 --><!-- Begin Popup 2 --><div id="popupProject2" class="popup-inline-content"><h2 class="mt-lg">ترجمه و ویرایش</h2><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive mb-lg" alt="" src="/assets/landing/img/projects/translation.jpg"></div><div class="col-md-7"><h4 class="heading-primary mb-sm">نیاز به <strong>ترجمه</strong> یک متن داری؟</h4><p class="iraniansans-light-font">ترجمه یکی از کارهایی هست که زیاد در پارسکدرز انجام میشه. مترجمان ماهری در پارسکدرز فعالیت دارند که هم ترجمه عمومی انجام میدن و هم ترجمه تخصصی.</p><a href="/my-project/create" class="btn btn-primary">سفارش پروژه ترجمه</a><span class="arrow hlb"></span><hr class="solid tall"><h4 class="heading-primary mt-lg">مراحل انجام کار</h4><ul class="list list-icons"><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ثبت درخواست</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> دیده شدن توسط مجریان</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ارسال پیشنهاد برای شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> انتخاب بهترین پیشنهاد</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> گروگذاری وجه از سوی شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> تحویل کار از سوی مجری</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> آزاد کردن وجه از جانب شما</li></ul></div></div></div><!-- End Popup 2 --><!-- Begin Popup 3 --><div id="popupProject3" class="popup-inline-content"><h2 class="mt-lg">طراحی وب</h2><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive mb-lg" alt="" src="/assets/landing/img/projects/web-design.jpg"></div><div class="col-md-7"><h4 class="heading-primary mb-sm">قصد داری یک <strong>سایت</strong> بسازی؟</h4><p class="iraniansans-light-font">تا دلت بخواد طراح و توسعه دهنده ی وب داریم توی پارسکدرز. این یعنی اینکه می تونی مطمئن باشی که پیشنهادات خوبی برای نیازت دریافت می کنی.</p><a href="/my-project/create" class="btn btn-primary">سفارش پروژه طراحی وب</a><span class="arrow hlb"></span><hr class="solid tall"><h4 class="heading-primary mt-lg">مراحل انجام کار</h4><ul class="list list-icons"><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ثبت درخواست</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> دیده شدن توسط مجریان</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ارسال پیشنهاد برای شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> انتخاب بهترین پیشنهاد</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> گروگذاری وجه از سوی شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> تحویل کار از سوی مجری</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> آزاد کردن وجه از جانب شما</li></ul></div></div></div><!-- End Popup 3 --><!-- Begin Popup 4 --><div id="popupProject4" class="popup-inline-content"><h2 class="mt-lg">برنامه نویسی</h2><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive mb-lg" alt="" src="/assets/landing/img/projects/programming.jpg"></div><div class="col-md-7"><h4 class="heading-primary mb-sm">قصد داری یک <strong>نرم افزار</strong> بسازی؟</h4><p class="iraniansans-light-font">هر نوع نیاز برنامه نویسی که داشته باشی می تونی توی پارسکدرز مطرحش کنی. از برنامه نویسی میکروکنترلر تا ساختن اپلیکیشن موبایل. می تونی مشکلت رو مطرح کنی یا اینکه یه پروژه کامل رو سفارش بدی.</p><a href="/my-project/create" class="btn btn-primary">سفارش پروژه برنامه نویسی</a><span class="arrow hlb"></span><hr class="solid tall"><h4 class="heading-primary mt-lg">مراحل انجام کار</h4><ul class="list list-icons"><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ثبت درخواست</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> دیده شدن توسط مجریان</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ارسال پیشنهاد برای شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> انتخاب بهترین پیشنهاد</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> گروگذاری وجه از سوی شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> تحویل کار از سوی مجری</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> آزاد کردن وجه از جانب شما</li></ul></div></div></div><!-- End Popup 4 --><!-- Begin Popup 5 --><div id="popupProject5" class="popup-inline-content"><h2 class="mt-lg">SEO - بهینه سازی برای موتورجستجو</h2><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive mb-lg" alt="" src="/assets/landing/img/projects/seo.jpg"></div><div class="col-md-7"><h4 class="heading-primary mb-sm">دوست داری <strong>سایتت</strong> بهینه بشه؟</h4><p class="iraniansans-light-font">نیاز به توضیح نیست که SEO سایت چقدر مهمه. اگر نیاز داری وب سایتت بهینه بشه کافیه که درخواستش رو توی پارسکدرز ثبت کنی.</p><a href="/my-project/create" class="btn btn-primary">سفارش پروژه سئو</a><span class="arrow hlb"></span><hr class="solid tall"><h4 class="heading-primary mt-lg">مراحل انجام کار</h4><ul class="list list-icons"><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ثبت درخواست</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> دیده شدن توسط مجریان</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ارسال پیشنهاد برای شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> انتخاب بهترین پیشنهاد</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> گروگذاری وجه از سوی شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> تحویل کار از سوی مجری</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> آزاد کردن وجه از جانب شما</li></ul></div></div></div><!-- End Popup 5 --><!-- Begin Popup 6 --><div id="popupProject6" class="popup-inline-content"><h2 class="mt-lg">خدمات آموزشی</h2><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive mb-lg" alt="" src="/assets/landing/img/projects/educational.jpg"></div><div class="col-md-7"><h4 class="heading-primary mb-sm">نیاز به<strong>رفع اشکال یا آموزش</strong> داری؟</h4><p class="iraniansans-light-font">اگر دانشجو هستی و برای انجام پروژه هات با مشکل مواجه هستی یا نیاز داری یه نفر مباحثی رو بهت آموزش بده جای درستی اومدی.</p><a href="/my-project/create" class="btn btn-primary">سفارش پروژه آموزشی</a><span class="arrow hlb"></span><hr class="solid tall"><h4 class="heading-primary mt-lg">مراحل انجام کار</h4><ul class="list list-icons"><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ثبت درخواست</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> دیده شدن توسط مجریان</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ارسال پیشنهاد برای شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> انتخاب بهترین پیشنهاد</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> گروگذاری وجه از سوی شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> تحویل کار از سوی مجری</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> آزاد کردن وجه از جانب شما</li></ul></div></div></div><!-- End Popup 6 --><!-- Begin Popup 7 --><div id="popupProject7" class="popup-inline-content"><h2 class="mt-lg">گرافیک</h2><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive mb-lg" alt="" src="/assets/landing/img/projects/graphics.jpg"></div><div class="col-md-7"><h4 class="heading-primary mb-sm">نیاز به <strong>طراح و گرافیست</strong> داری؟</h4><p class="iraniansans-light-font">توی پارسکدرز مجریان هنرمندی داریم که پاسخگوی نیازهای طراحی شما هستند. از طراحی لوگو گرفته تا طراحی سه بعدی و تیزر!</p><a href="/my-project/create" class="btn btn-primary">سفارش طراحی</a><span class="arrow hlb"></span><hr class="solid tall"><h4 class="heading-primary mt-lg">مراحل انجام کار</h4><ul class="list list-icons"><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ثبت درخواست</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> دیده شدن توسط مجریان</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> ارسال پیشنهاد برای شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> انتخاب بهترین پیشنهاد</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> گروگذاری وجه از سوی شما</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> تحویل کار از سوی مجری</li><li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> آزاد کردن وجه از جانب شما</li></ul></div></div></div><!-- End Popup 7 --><div class="owl-carousel" data-plugin-options='{"items": 5, "margin": 20, "loop": false}'><div><a href="#popupProject1" data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options='{"type": "inline", preloader: false}'><span class="thumb-info"><span class="thumb-info-wrapper"><img src="/assets/landing/img/projects/typing.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="تایپ ارزان و سریع"><span class="thumb-info-title"><span class="thumb-info-inner">تایپ</span><span class="thumb-info-type">راحت و سریع</span></span><span class="thumb-info-action"><span class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span></span></span></span></a></div><div><a href="#popupProject2" data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options='{"type": "inline", preloader: false}'><span class="thumb-info"><span class="thumb-info-wrapper"><img src="/assets/landing/img/projects/translation.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ترجمه"><span class="thumb-info-title"><span class="thumb-info-inner">ترجمه و ویرایش</span><span class="thumb-info-type">مترجمان حرفه ای</span></span><span class="thumb-info-action"><span class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span></span></span></span></a></div><div><a href="#popupProject3" data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options='{"type": "inline", preloader: false}'><span class="thumb-info"><span class="thumb-info-wrapper"><img src="/assets/landing/img/projects/web-design.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="طراحی وب"><span class="thumb-info-title"><span class="thumb-info-inner">طراحی وب</span><span class="thumb-info-type">توسط حرفه ای ها</span></span><span class="thumb-info-action"><span class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span></span></span></span></a></div><div><a href="#popupProject4" data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options='{"type": "inline", preloader: false}'><span class="thumb-info"><span class="thumb-info-wrapper"><img src="/assets/landing/img/projects/programming.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="برنامه نویسی"><span class="thumb-info-title"><span class="thumb-info-inner">برنامه نویسی</span><span class="thumb-info-type">هر زبانی که بخواهید</span></span><span class="thumb-info-action"><span class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span></span></span></span></a></div><div><a href="#popupProject7" data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options='{"type": "inline", preloader: false}'><span class="thumb-info"><span class="thumb-info-wrapper"><img src="/assets/landing/img/projects/graphics.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="طراحی و گرافیک"><span class="thumb-info-title"><span class="thumb-info-inner">گرافیک</span><span class="thumb-info-type">طراحی دو بعدی و سه بعدی</span></span><span class="thumb-info-action"><span class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span></span></span></span></a></div><div><a href="#popupProject5" data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options='{"type": "inline", preloader: false}'><span class="thumb-info"><span class="thumb-info-wrapper"><img src="/assets/landing/img/projects/seo.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="SEO و بهینه سازی برای موتورهای جستجو"><span class="thumb-info-title"><span class="thumb-info-inner">SEO</span><span class="thumb-info-type">تولید محتوا و بهینه سازی</span></span><span class="thumb-info-action"><span class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span></span></span></span></a></div><div><a href="#popupProject6" data-plugin-lightbox data-plugin-options='{"type": "inline", preloader: false}'><span class="thumb-info"><span class="thumb-info-wrapper"><img src="/assets/landing/img/projects/educational.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="آموزشی"><span class="thumb-info-title"><span class="thumb-info-inner">آموزشی</span><span class="thumb-info-type">کمک درسی و رفع اشکال</span></span><span class="thumb-info-action"><span class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span></span></span></span></a></div></div><br><section class="call-to-action featured featured-primary mb-none"><div class="call-to-action-content"><h3 class="custom-call-to-action-h text-right">دوست داری طرز کار پارسکدرز رو تماشا کنی؟</h3><p class="custom-call-to-action-p text-right">داستان پارسکدرز رو توی چند ثانیه به تصویر کشیدیم.</p></div><style>
                                .h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame{position:relative;} .h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame .ratio {display:block;width:100%;height:auto;} .h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%;}
                            </style><div class="h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame"><span style="display: block;padding-top: 57%"></span><iframe src="https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/q8oSX/vt/frame" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0"></iframe></div></section></div></div></div></section><div class="container"><div class="row mb-xlg"><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><h2 class="home-h2">کسب درآمد به عنوان مجری یا فریلنسر</h2><p class="home-info-p ">
                        اگر
                        <a href="/فریلنسر" target="_blank">فریلنسر</a> هستی یا توانایی انجام کارهای سفارش داده شده از جانب خریداران رو داری می تونی اقدام به کسب در آمد از پارسکدرز کنی. از تایپ و ترجمه گرفته تا طراحی گرافیکی، برنامه نویسی و پیاده سازی سیستم های بزرگ.
                    </p><p class="home-info-p mt-xlg">
                        پارسکدرز با استفاده از سیستم مالی گروگذاری وجه <span class="blue-highlight"> امنیت مالی طرفین </span> را تضمین می کند. این به این معنی است که شما پس از اطمینان از انجام صحیح پروژه حتما هزینه انجام کار را دریافت می کنید.
                    </p><section class="call-to-action featured featured-tertiary mb-xl" data-appear-animation="fadeInUp" data-appear-animation-delay="100"><div class="call-to-action-content"><h3 class="custom-call-to-action-h">شروع به ارسال پیشنهاد کن</h3><p class="custom-call-to-action-p">پروژه هایی وجود داره که مطمئنا می تونی انجامشون بدی.</p></div><div class="call-to-action-btn"><a href="/register/" class="btn btn-3d btn-lg btn-success mr-xs mb-sm" target="_blank" href="#">
                                ثبت نام
                            </a></a></div></section></div><div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-1 mt-xlg" data-appear-animation="fadeInLeft" data-appear-animation-delay="100"><img alt="" src="/assets/landing/img/device.png" class="img-responsive mt-xlg"></div></div></div><section class="call-to-action call-to-action-tertiary" style="margin: 0"><img src="/assets/global/img/invitation_emails_sent_white.png" style="position: absolute; width: 240px; left: 0px;" class="hidden-xs"><div class="container"><br><br><h3 class="home-h2 text-center">نه کارفرما هستی و نه مجری؟</h3><p ...
```

Comment: Please give us an idea on what exception you are encountering, Reply with `r.text` please.

Comment: I think there no exception or error involved. the content of `r.text` is just the login page again.  @SalmanFarsi

Comment: I checked the website, turns out it's set to a `302` response, It will present a success or false response and then you'll have to manually send another request to the dashboard.